# Python says "Please enable JavaScript and Cookies in your browser." in Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
url=""
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,  "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

When i try to use the selenium, "window.onload=function(){process();}

Please enable JavaScript and Cookies in your browser.

" is shown. How can i enable JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling javascript:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
```

Comment: Same error Please enable JavaScript and Cookies in your browser.:( @Kurohige